# Trying to understand which DB option is for me when hosting a web app in Azure

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, azure, nosql

I am in the process of creating my first web application top to bottom as a learning experience which I want to deploy in Azure. I wanted to start this from an Empty web project so I can really see all the core components that make up a web api service.

I have created the application using the template created from this tutorial: http://www.daniellewis.me.uk/2015/03/23/web-api-with-owin-bootstrap-and-angularjs-from-scratch-part-1/

and am in middle of adding user authentication by following this tutorial:
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

So now I have gotten to the point where I have to add a connection string to my web.config file:

```
   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="AuthContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=AngularJSAuth;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I am assuming (me being a noob) that my application fails because clearly it isn't hooked up to any sort of database server. So now I have gotten to the point where I have to I guess choose my DB option, set it up, *create tables?*, and then pass in the correct connection string into my web.config.

I figured I would stick as closely to Azure as possible since that is where I will be deploying (developing this application with Angular front end, OWIN C# backend), but I see a few different database options available for me whether it be Azure SQL Database or Azure NoSQL DB.

My database and application needs are:

- Store user credentials (username, password, credit card information)
- Store PDF files temporarily (30 days)

In this application there will be very few number of user account creations with this information, but alot of reads from the PDF files that are associated with each account.

I am looking mainly for opinions on what DB structure would be correct for me, I obviously have misunderstandings on:

- If one SQL Database can handle all of my needs, or if I need a DB for user accounts and information and then another for PDF storage
- Best way to store PDF's, either converting them to BLOB's and handle conversion back and forth in my application logic or storing the actual file? DocumentDB?
- How to handle my temporary storage use case where PDF files would be stored for 30 days, or if I should handle this separately all together.

I know this is alot but I am mainly looking for experiences and resources for me to learn more rather than a straight forward answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorials you're following build on top of the ASP.NET Identity subsystem, which has a provider model that abstracts the underlying storage of users, etc. In your case the most straightforward approach is to use Azure SQL Database:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/

...along with the Entity Framework provider referenced in your second link. Azure SQL DB is nice because you can use familiar tools like SQL Management Studio, etc. to set things up and poke around.

Note that there are other providers out there in the wild, and you're of course free to write your own. For example here's one that talks to MongoDB:

http://devblog.weshigbee.name/posts/building-a-mongodb-provider-for-the-new-asp.net-identity-framework-part-2-rolestore-and-sample

Unless you have a compelling reason to choose otherwise, Azure SQL DB is a good place to start.

As for your PDF storage, you could use Azure SQL for that too but that's not ideal from a cost and performance standpoint. Azure Blob storage is very cheap and well-suited to storing and serving files and binary data. You can store PDF metadata (links to users, URI pointers to specific blobs, etc.) in the SQL DB and keep the actual PDF content in blob storage where its cheaper. You'll have to write some code to keep PDF metadata and content in sync but that's typical for these kinds of polyglot persistence solutions in the cloud.

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PolyglotPersistence.html

So, to answer your questions specifically:

- consider using separate storage for user accounts and other discrete metadata and another for PDF content
- consider blob storage for the PDF content (DocumentDB is possible but blob storage is still much cheaper)
- blob storage will work fine for either temporary or permanent storage of the PDFs

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the response! 
So if I create a Azure SQL DB from the Azure Portal that just creates the DB and Server with no tables, and the Entity Framework is what handles the table creation and management from my application logic? I assume creating the SQL database from the portal will provide me with the information I need to update my connectionString in my web.config file?

I will experiment and try this out now, thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that's basically it. There are some important differences between SQL Azure and regular on-prem SQL Server but from the perspective of your code (at least in your demo) you can treat them the same. Code- or db-first EF scenarios still work, etc. Cheers!